# Finding a process by argument string

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, ps

I'm using `ps`, `grep`, and `sed` to try to identify some java processes that are uniquely identified by some specific argument, e.g. `-DAppService=DDDABC_456` or `-DAppService=DDDXYZ_456_cazorla`.  I want to return a comma separated list: `PID,argument,process`

I'm working on CentOS7.  So far I'm only about half way down the line but getting tangled up.

I'm shooting for this:

```
1234,-DAppService=DDDABC_456,/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java
2345,-DAppService=DDDABC_456_cazorla,/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java
3456,-DAppService=DDDXYZ_789,/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java
4567,-DAppService=DDDXYZ_789_cazorla,/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java
```

Note that the argument may or may not have a suffix of "_cazorla".

I tried this but it loses the arguments (and the number of arguments may vary so I don't think I can continue with $9, $10, etc.):

```
ps -ef | grep DAppService=DDD[A-Z]*_[0-9]*(?:_[a-z]*)? | grep -v grep | awk '{OFS=","; print $2,$8}'
```

Gives me:

```
1234,/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java
2345,/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java
3456,/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java
4567,/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java
```

Also this which comma separates all the grep column results and all arguments too which I don't want:

```
ps -aef | grep DAppService=DDD[A-Z]*_[0-9]*(?:_[a-z]*)? | grep -v grep | sed -e "s/\s\+/,/g"
```

Actual result too much to list here but e.g.

```
user,1234,1,0,Jul03,pts/0,00:03:21,/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java,arg1,arg2,arg3,argn...
user,2345,1,0,Jul03,pts/0,00:03:21,/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java,arg1,arg2,arg3,argn...
user,3456,1,0,Jul03,pts/0,00:03:21,/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java,arg1,arg2,arg3,argn...
user,4567,1,0,Jul03,pts/0,00:03:21,/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java,arg1,arg2,arg3,argn...
```

My sed knowledge is pretty poor (as is awk but would be open to that as an option too).  Once I'm happy with the commands I want to put them into a bash script that I can call from elsewhere.

Comment: It's great that you put your problem in context, but to help with awk and/or sed the most helpful would be to show what is actually being input into those commands --- that is, to include in your question the output of `ps -aef | grep DAppService=DDD[A-Z]*_[0-9]*(?:_[a-z]*)? | grep -v grep`

Comment: does your `ps` understand `-o spec=name` ?

Comment: Hi @jhnc, it errors with "error: unknown user-defined format specifier "spec"".  I'm also not sure if it would work on my client's box.  I know that I can get the output with ps and I know that I can process the output with grep/sed/awk.

Comment: Hi @jas this is for a client and the data is sensitive so I'm having to obfuscate a bit.  Replacing the DAppService=DDD[A-Z]*_[0-9]*(?:_[a-z]*)? with any argument from any process in the ps -ef output will generate the same result format however.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -eo pid=,args= |\
awk '
    {
        for (i=3; i<=NF; i++)
            if ($i ~ regex) {
                print $1, $i, $2
                next
            }
    }
' OFS=, regex='awk re to match arg'
```

- ask `ps` to output just pid and the commandline
- specify a regex to `awk` and have it check each argument (fields 3 to NF) for a match
- if found, output pid (`$1`), command (`$2`), and the relevant argument (`$i`)

---

**Notes:**

- awk can't distinguish `cmd "arg1 with spaces"` from `cmd arg1 arg2 arg3` but that may not matter here
- spaces in the command (eg. in a directory name in the path) will cause the command to be truncated at the first space
- commas in the command (or the relevant argument) will break the csv output

Comment: Thanks for the input jhnc, it did help me formulate my script and also build my understanding of ps and awk but I ended up with something more long-winded and human readable.